# React test tools + Jest. Cannot equal two objects

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, redux-saga

So, I try to make a little test for my Redux component and in this test I send just empty obj `{}`. And try to equal it in my test file like `expect(get).toEqual(obj)`. What I got in Error log:

```sh
$ yarn test
yarn run v1.5.1
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts test --env=jsdom
 FAIL  src\saga\saga.test.js
  ● get new action value

expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  {}
Received:
  {}

Difference:

- Expected
+ Received

-Object {}
+ {}

  at Object.<anonymous>.test (src/saga/saga.test.js:10:17)
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
      at <anonymous>
```

× get new action value (15ms)

My `test.js` file:

```js
import { put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { delay } from 'redux-saga'
import mySaga from './saga';

test('get new action value', () => {
    const get = mySaga();
    const data = 'hi1';
    const obj = {};

    expect(get).toEqual(obj);
});
```

My saga.js file:

```js
import { takeEvery, put, call, take } from 'redux-saga/effects'; 
import { delay } from 'redux-saga';

function* createSaga(action) {
    try {
        yield call(delay, 1000);
        yield put({type: "ADD_DAT", data: action.data + 1});
    } catch (e) { 
        console.log(e) 
    }
};

function* mySaga() {
    yield takeEvery("ADD_DATA", createSaga);
};

export default mySaga;
```

Comment: Please show the source for `mySaga`.

Comment: @mpontus added.

Comment: `mySaga()` returns a [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator), which is not equal to an empty object. The error is thrown because the assertion `expect(get).toEqual(obj)` expectedly fails. Does this make it clear?

Comment: @mpontus Ok, and how we can solve it and make our condition trusly in case that reseived `{}` from generator are the same as in the test condition `{}`?

Comment: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html

Answer (score 0):

When you call `const get = mySaga();` you're assigning an instance of the `mySaga` generator to the variable `get`. Since you are using the right Jest matcher, [`toEqual`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#toequalvalue), to compare two objects your test failure is expected.

When the expected and actual values are compared, the `toEqual` matcher will (eventually) compare the stingified object prototypes. The prototype of `get` will be `'[object Generator]'` is not equal to `'[object Object]'` and your test fails.

As suggested in the comments, have a look at the [redux-saga testing docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Testing.html) to get an idea of how you can get up to speed with testing them. Since you're using a `delay`, you'll probably also want to have a look at the Jest Docs for [Timer Mocks](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html) to help you fake time.